# Windows Subsystem for Linux git mergetool meld UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: git, utf-8, windows-subsystem-for-linux, meld, mergetool

I'm WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) user.
I use WSL to simply rsync source code between my host and remote compiling machine (RedHat). I found such a article:

```
https://www.deptagency.com/en-gb/story/using-meld-as-a-git-merge-tool-on-windows/
```

which triggers and run GUI windows meld from WSL.

But after following steps from this article, I'm getting this err msg (I've checked if windows EoL were passed):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/meld", line 328, in structured_log_adapter
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 103: invalid start byte

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
BR

Comment: A bug report here:[Meld Windows shows error when git external call it (#222) · Issues · GNOME / meld · GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/meld/issues/222), and it looks like a binding error.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if it would answer this question, but I needed to run `meld` within WSL2. Tried `apt install meld` but since that it's Windows, it doesn't run GTK app. So what I have done was to simply use symbolic link between Windows version of Meld:

```
ln -s /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Meld/Meld.exe /usr/local/bin/meld
```

And voila!

Comment: Works great. Exactly what I needed for WSL2 on Win10.

Comment: If I do this, Meld.exe cannot open the files since they start from /mnt/e, instead of E:\. How did you overcome this?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried the current version of Meld https://meldmerge.org/. I have followed the provided link https://www.deptagency.com/en-gb/story/using-meld-as-a-git-merge-tool-on-windows/ without any issues.

**Steps in detail**

Download and Install meld on Windows 10 from https://meldmerge.org/

Navigate to your wsl terminal
Create a script to pass things over to meld

```sh
nano meld
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Meld/Meld.exe $@
```

Make the script executable

```sh
sudo chmod +x meld
```

Move the script to `/usr/bin`

```sh
sudo mv meld /usr/bin
```

Then, in `~/.gitconfig` add/edit the following

```sh
[merge]
    tool = meld
[mergetool "meld"]
    cmd = meld --diff \"$BASE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" --output \"$MERGED\"
```

Navigate to git directory that has merge conflicts

Run

```sh
git mergetool
```

Enjoy!